# Echo/Print something to page with delay in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to make a page that will show some results after executing some processes. Each process may take 2-10 seconds. So instead of waiting for all the processes to complete, I want to print the result of each once it is completed.

Eg:

```
<?php

echo "1";

sleep(5); // some process that will execute 5 seconds

echo "2"

sleep(8); // some process that will execute 8 seconds

echo "3"

sleep(5); // some process that will execute 5 seconds

?>
```

So on opening this PHP file in browsers, "1" prints, after 5 seconds "2" and son on. How can I do that I PHP? One way to do that is to convert these to separate PHP files and load each of then with ajax. But I don't want to split it into different files.

Comment: You have probably given the best answer yourself: Creating multiple scripts and loading them dynamically. Pure PHP: `flush()` contents, but that is probably a bad practice

Comment: You have to use ajax. There are a built-in function in PHP: [`flush()`](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php), but with unpredictable results (the question affects also browsers behavior).

Comment: @kingkero what about inserting data to database? because database insertion doesn't wait for the whole php program to complete. From the browser use ajax to find what new in database (of course another php is need for that) But we don't have to split into number of parts

Answer (score 0):

use actions to separate the different parts of the script. that way you don't have to break into separate scripts.

```
$action = empty($_REQUEST['action']) ? null : $_REQUEST['action'];
switch($action){
    case 1:
        // do stuff
        break;
    case 2:
        // do stuff
        break;
    case 3:
        // do stuff
        break;
    case 4:
        // do stuff
        break; 
    default:
        echo "you fucked up";   
}
```

Then use ajax like

```
function doAjax(action){
  if('undefined' == typeof(action)) action = 1;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
      action++;
      if(action<4) doAjax(action);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "myPHPScript.php?action="+encodeURIComponent(action), true);
  xhttp.send();
}
doAjax();
```

Comment: @Pamblam really its a good idea. I too have thought about that one. But can't use it. Because, the 2nd process depends on the output of 1st. 3rd process depends on 2nd. It goes like that

Comment: you could use it if you can send the output from the first back to the second.. you could add a nother parameter to the recursive function to send back the output of the pervious call back to the next. or you could use sessions to hold the output of the last script.

Comment: You _could_ check out WebSockets and/or the more user-friendly implementation socket.io.

Comment: @Dencker it can output data from the middle of a php execution?

Comment: Yes it will :) That's exactly what it does.